# Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'postImageView'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

New to iOS programming, I am getting the following error, I get it for 3 separate items, but solving one will solve them all.

I am getting the following error

Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'postImageView'

```
// return how may records in a table
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.rssRecordList.count
    }

    // return cell
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NewsTableViewCell {

        // collect reusable cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        // find record for current cell
        let thisRecord : RssRecord  = self.rssRecordList[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        // set value for main title and detail tect
        cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(thisRecord.image)
        cell.postTitleLabel.text = thisRecord.title
        cell.authorLabel.text = thisRecord.storyDate


        // return cell
        return cell as! NewsTableViewCell
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your cell object is a UITableViewCell and not a NewsTableViewCell. You need to dequeue a NewsTableViewCell that will actually have those properties on it.

Something like:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the following lines:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell

...

return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.dequeueReusableCell` returns a `UITableViewCell` which (as the compiler tells you) does not have the properties you are asking for.
You will have to cast it to the expected type `NewsTableViewCell`:

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell`